# Write a javascript program to Delete Even occurrences in a given string

Tags: javascript, function

I am finding problem in JavaScript code.
Write a JavaScript program to delete even occurrence in given string using function.
for example :

Input  A**A**AB**B**BC**C**C
OUTPUT:  AABBCC (delet bold letters)

Input: A**A**A**A**B**B**B**B**C**C**C**C**
OUTPUT:  AABBCC

i am facing problem in function

Comment: It's really hard to debug without a.) you showing your function and b.) you describing your problem. What's the expected result vs actual result?

Answer (score 0):

A single regex should work:

```js
console.log(remove('AAABBBCCC'))
console.log(remove('AAAABBBBCCCC')) 

function remove(str) {
  return str.replace(/(.)\1/g, '$1')
}
```

`(.)\1` matches duplicated characters

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a for loop:

```js
function stripEven(str) {
  let res = '';
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] !== str[i-1]) counter = 0;
    if (counter % 2 === 0) res += str[i];
    counter++;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(stripEven('AAABBBCCC'))
console.log(stripEven('AAAABBBBCCCC'))
console.log(stripEven('AAABBCCC'))
```